Call function within a worksheet not working when calling another macro from the same workbook, but the macro run ok on its own
I have a workbook for calculating labour rates for either 1no. base location and 1 no. destination i.e only one travel payment or multiple multiple base locations and multiples destinations. but I only want to show the relevant worksheets for either one of the two previous options. I have created macros to hide and unhide worksheets and these work successfully on their own. There are a total of 4 variations i.e
Electrical - Single site
Electrical - Multisite (there are 12 sheets that this macro hides)
Mechanical - Single site
Mechanical - Multisite (there are 12 sheets that this macro hides)
The calulation sheets 'pull' data from a commmon hidden admin sheet which is updated as required
The work book has a Project Data worksheet into which data that is common to any of the above is entered.
The work book is set up so that by default all of the options are hidden
In the Project Data worksheet I have entered the following
cell A10 Electrical  Single Site
Cell B12 Yes/No selected from a drop down
I have following code to the Project Data worksheet
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Set Target = Range("B10")
If Target.Value = "Yes" Then
Call OpenElecSingleSiteSheet
End If
If Target.Value = "No" Then
Call HideElecSingleSiteSheet
End Sub
The macros that have been called are:-
Sub HideElecSingleSiteSheetByName()
Sheets("Elec - Single Site").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
   

End Sub
Sub OpenElecSingleSiteSheetByName()
Sheets("Elec - Single Site").Visible = True

End Sub
When the worksheets have been hidden using the macros individually selecting yes does not unhide the sheet.
Can you please advise why?
My plan was to copy the target range  for the other options with target ranges being "B12"; "B14" & "B16"
However, ideally I would like two main options on the project data worksheet Electrical or Mechanical with a toggle button for each that selects between single site and multisite
Any assistance you can give would be appreciated
